# KnexJS Raw Method doesn't work in one case

Tags: node.js, knex.js

Working with KnexJS on a project and have been using the `.raw()` method throughout the project with out a single issue.

I now have one case where the `.raw` is just not being built into the SQL, and so I end up with the `syntax error at end of input` error.   If I dump the SQL string, I can see why as it's failing

```
'update "mytable" set "a" = ? returning '
```

I can see why it's having an issue, the problem I'm having is that the returning is a `Raw` value as such, and so I just can't figure out why it's not being compiled with the SQL.

```
knexQuery.update(data).into('mytable').returning( knexQuery.raw('mytable::json') );`
```

If I use a string, in place of the `raw` in the `returning()` method, it will compile the string into it.

If I console out the `knexQuery.raw('mytable::json')` part, it shows as a Raw object, with the right object data...

```
Raw {
 client: 
  Client_PG {
    ... },
 sql: 'mytable::json',
 bindings: undefined,
 _wrappedBefore: undefined,
 _wrappedAfter: undefined,
 _debug: undefined } }
```

I know that the SQL works, as I've filled in the missing part and it works, but the SQL is not the issue, I just can't figure out why the `raw()` method is not being compiled with the SQL string.

I also have another piece of code (and `INSERT` one) somewhere else in my code that is using the same `returning( knexQuery.raw(....) )` and that works perfectly fine.

I'm starting to think this is a bug in the code, but after spending an hour going through the KnexJS library code, I can't see any reason why it would not work.

*So why does this code not build the raw into the query, while my other one has no problem and works?*

I'm getting to the point where I just want to use something else to get around the problem, but it's just not possible without using this method.

Comment: Have you tried `knexQuery('mytable').update(data).returning( knexQuery.raw('mytable::json') );` I can not find any usage of `update` and `into` together in the doc (this might be only for `insert`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is bug in `knex` https://runkit.com/mikaelle/592412c3a631940012a51928 please open issue in knex github. Looks like handling raw input just haven't been implemented to `returning` builder method.

Anyways looks like this works as a workaround:

```
knex('TestTable')
  .insert({ foo: 'bar' })
  .returning([knex.raw('mytable::json')]) // raw wrapped in array
  .toSQL();
```

Comment: Hi Mikael, thanks for that.  Hehe, I just managed to solve that with the same glitch/workaround.